# Open Safari from Application and get selected content

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I need to open safari from my application and get the content selected by the user from that WebPage into my application.

[Video Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCRyOZ8rTCE)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SFSafariViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller) to open Safari from your application and then check the [UIPasteboard](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipasteboard) to see if the user has copied some text.

Answer (score 0):

```
let url = URL(string:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCRyOZ8rTCE"!) 
let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
  safariVC.preferredBarTintColor = UIColor(red: 46.0/255.0, green: 135.0/255.0, blue: 245.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
   } else {
  // Fallback on earlier versions
   }//UIColor.black
   present(safariVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```